# Rails API only app needs to preview files(docx xlsx pdf png jpg) from S3 in mobile app(react native) is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, amazon-s3

I am working on the Backend application in rails 6 API only.

In my app(react native) I need to preview files from the S3 url. I know its totally front end functionality but they are not able to achieve this. Can I achieve this from the backend?

I have API only app and for the preview, I need something like this.

```
<%= image_tag message.video.preview(resize_to_limit: [100, 100]) %>
```

But how to implement that?

Is that possible to do it from the backend side to preview files with the use of API?

Note: I need to do it without downloading the file